# PHP: JSON format outputs into one long single line

Tags: php, json, api

here is my PHP script.

```
do2:locu alexus$ cat venuesearch.php 
<?php

$KEY='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$URL='http://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=';

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL.$KEY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);

print_r(json_decode(curl_exec($ch),TRUE));

?>
do2:locu alexus$
```

`locu` service provides output in JSON format. When I run script I'm getting output all in long single line.

sample of output:

```
do2:locu alexus$ php venuesearch.php 
{"meta": {"cache-expiry": 3600, "limit": 25}, "objects": [{"categories": ["restaurant"], "country": "United States",..........
```

What am I missing? How can I access each of those variables? maybe it makes sense to convert it into XML?

*** UPDATE *** : .. in example #1 of [PHP: json_decode - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) shows formated output, if I use `true` then I get array, I'm not getting neither formatet output nor array.

Comment: im not sure where you would like to access it.

Comment: whats wrong with output JSON format into one long single line?

Comment: You can access it through: 
$var = json_decode();
$var['key'] eg.

Comment: When you parse the JSON in PHP, you get back a PHP array or object and can do whatever you want to do with it. Doesn't http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php explain it? But the output you posted shouldn't be the result of `json_decode`. Are you sure you are not printing the response directly? And no, it does not make sense to convert a data format into another one in this case, you just have to parse the data properly.

Comment: > *"maybe it makes sense to convert it into XML"* - heh, then you've got 2 problems.

Comment: I apologize for not such a smart question, i'm new) I'm trying to work with data that I'm getting from provider, as first step to make it readable on screen, but all in one line is not readable for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

before execution.

It looks like the execution is simply printing the response rather than returning it as a string to be processed by json_decode.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Makes more sense than my answer :) The tricky thing is that `print_r(null)` outputs nothing. A good reason to use `var_dump` instead...

Comment: @fab Your answer is still good because separating each procedure can help to identify the probelm. alexus, I would still take a look at fab's answer to isolate the problem because it's far easier to debug each individual function call rather than a bunch of nested calls.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the original data:

```
$json = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($json);
```

Your described output is only possible if the API returns a json encoded json string, like that:

```
"{\"meta\": {\"cache-expiry\": 3600, \"limit\": 25}, \"objects\": [{\"categories\": [\"restaurant\"], \"country\": \"United States\",.......... '
```

(note the outer quotes, they are part of the string)

This is very weird and definitly a bug in the API but the only way to get around it is to decode it twice:

```
$data = json_decode(json_decode($json));
```

**Edit:** Forget that, [Stegrex has figured it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15057910/664108).